Can you write a non-recursive/non-iterative but computable function?
According to here a single loop and four basic arithmetic operation is enough to simulate a Turing machine.
My question is what if we unroll the loop and use only composition of four function.

$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{div}(n,m) &=
   \begin{cases}
      \operatorname{sgn}(mn)\left\lfloor \left|\dfrac{n}{m}\right| \right\rfloor & \text{if $m \neq 0$} \\
      \text{halt and return $n$} & \text{if $m = 0$} \\
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
$
$\operatorname{mul}(n,m) = n \times m$
$\operatorname{sub}(n,m) = n - m$
$\operatorname{inc}(n) = n + 1$

Can you construct a universal function (for unrolled functions) or square root or nth digit of golden ratio using these?
Thanks
